# Disable MassAssignmentSecurity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

Is there a way of completely disabling the MassAssignmentSecurity feature in Rails3?

We're busy with an upgrade and need to disable it for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `config/application.rb` you can set the `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` to `false` so you have the opposite situation, you have to blacklsit attributes that shouldnt be accessible. On the bottom line that would do what you want,...

Comment: I must be honest. I've found this feature of Rails to be really temperamental. We've set that flag to both true and false with absolutely no change in behaviour...

Comment: Note: for rails 4 migrators..  If you're using the protected_attributes gem, that gem sets whitelist_attributes = true and overrides the setting in application.rb  [link](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/blob/b24a10e90e74fc4ce4af8ab1ce7c251e05356bed/lib/protected_attributes/railtie.rb)